# Create a button that lowers or increases the column width in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

I am trying to create two buttons one that increases the column width in ag-grid and another button that decreases the column width when clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get access to the latest column width using [`ColumnApi.getColumnState()`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-api) and update any columns width using [`ColumnApi.setColumnWidth()`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-api). Here is an example

```js
const changeWidth = (colId, offset) => () => {
  const currentWitdth = columnApi
    .getColumnState()
    .find((c) => c.colId === colId).width;
  columnApi.setColumnWidth(colId, currentWitdth + offset);
};
```

If you want to change the width of all columns

```js
const changeAllWidth = (offset) => () => {
  const columnState = columnApi.getColumnState();

  columnState.forEach((c) => {
    if (c.width) {
      columnApi.setColumnWidth(c.colId, c.width + offset);
    }
  });
};
```

### Usage

```
<button onClick={changeAllWidth(10)}>+ All</button>
<button onClick={changeAllWidth(-10)}>- All</button>

<button onClick={changeWidth("athlete", 10)}>+ athlete</button>
<button onClick={changeWidth("athlete", -10)}>- athlete</button>
<button onClick={changeWidth("age", 10)}>+ age</button>
<button onClick={changeWidth("age", -10)}>- age</button>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit AgGrid Update Column Width]

Comment: Thank you! you are the real MVP.

Comment: My problem was I had a group in the table

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Do you know how to apply this to groups?

Comment: The code in my answer should work fine with row groups. I've added row groups to the live demo. If you have any other problems, please add the relevant code in your question.

Comment: How to increase the height if the text of one column doesnot fit. i need to make it to the next line but minHeight is not applying